# How can I cleanly uninstall/delete WordPress from Azure?

Tags: wordpress, azure, uninstallation

I have a new Azure site, it was super-simple to install WordPress, but now I want to uninstall. But there appears to be no uninstaller. Do you know if there is one?

So I was going to manually delete WordPress.  I *am* able to FTP in and delete all files under wwwroot, but there must be more to do, I think.

Do I need to reconfigure or delete any files in any of the other folders?

Under Dashboard there is a linked resource to a MySQL database, but I can't see how to delete that linked resource reference. I *can* go to the account they created for me on cleardb.com and delete the database, but do I need to delete the linked resource back in Azure first?

Under Configure, under Connection Strings do I need to delete that? Is there anything else to do to manually uninstall/delete WordPress from Azure?

I guess the alternative is to just delete this Web Site and create a new one then I know there is no more WordPress, right? But I love the name I got and don't want to lose it. If I delete this web site, can I just re-create it using the same name?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress doesn't install like a regular software (with an installer). You just uncompress the wordpress files in a folder.

So, to uninstall it, you just need to delete all the files from the folder where you uncompressed it and then delete the MySQL database of wordpress. That's all.

To delete the Wordpress Database you should just go to the administration panel and then MySQL and delete the database containing "wordpress".

And, for the question about deleting your website, I would like to tell you that after deleting the domain, you can again set up another website with same name.

Comment: Thanks prakhar19, I may try deleting and recreating the website. I did delete all the files under wwwroot and it seems to be OK. But I definitely did not see any MySQL database referenced anywhere in Azure. During the install of WordPress an account and MySQL database were created for me at cleardb.com, and now there is a connection string to cloudapp.net under Configure, and there is still that "linked resource" under Dashboard. They also don't seem to be causing any issues, so maybe I'll leave them. Not totally clean, but seemingy working. See http://codethug.com/2012/06/18/mysql-on-azure/

Comment: They are not going to interfere with other files of your website. So, you may leave them as they are. The only problem they'll cause is take up some MBs.